# I need to find a way to make my code give time for the page to load, and only then grab the HTML code

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, real-time

So i wanted to grab a real time value from a website displaying *"the real time revolution of the earth's population"*, except when i run the code:

```py
import requests
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.theworldcounts.com/counters/shocking_environmental_facts_and_statistics/world_population_clock_live'

response = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')

population = soup.findAll('p', attrs={'class':'counter'})

print(population[0])
```

my output is:

```html
<p class="counter" id="counters_number_interveal_5">loading...</p>
```

The number i am looking to get is replaced by "*loading...*" so i am looking to find a way to actually get the value. Or an alternative to get the same result.

Answer (score 1):

You can wait for the page to load explicitly using `time.sleep()`, which will probably get the end-result you want. However, this isn't best practice and could end up waiting longer than the page needed to load.

I would recommend using Selenium instead, which has a multitude of useful features related to this; specifically it can implicitly wait.

The following is how you could use Selenium to wait until the counter is loaded, and not wait any longer.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException

url = 'https://www.theworldcounts.com/counters/shocking_environmental_facts_and_statistics/world_population_clock_live'
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get(url)

try:
    WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[@id=\"counters_number_interval_5\"]")))
    counter = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id=\"counters_number_interval_5\"]").text
    print(counter)
except TimeoutException:
    print("Timed out, couldn't load the page in time")
driver.quit()
```

You will need to install Selenium, but it's like installing BeautifulSoup - just use `pip install selenium`

Answer (score 0):

The website is still loading, perhaps use the time module to make the script wait for the answer.

```
import time
time.sleep(5)
#Wait 5 seconds for the answer
```

This should be added between the requests.get and the parsing with BeautifulSoup.

**EDIT**

Rereading your question, the problem is actually in the usage of requests, since it is downloading the html immediately, you need to add the timeout argument for the proper loading of the html:

```
response = requests.get(url, timeout = 5)
```

Comment: Yes that was my first thought, except for it to work i need to put it in between _"response.txt"_ and _"html.parser"_

```python

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')

```
Edit: And i have no idea of how to do it.

Comment: try the  "timeout" argument in the requests.get, might work. Its similar to what I said, but tells requests to wait the seconds you want before retrieving.

Comment: in your case: response = requests.get(url, timeout = 5)

Comment: I did try that, it did not work, what i did though is use prettify.

Now, the value i am looking for, does appear, except i don't know how to isolate the argument i was previously looking for (_"<p class="counter" id="counters_number_interveal_5">value i am looking for</p>
_)

Answer (score 0):

It's because you are targeting the wrong class. You can find the desired result within the second class with the same name `counter`. Try either of the two - one commented out and the other is active. They both produce the desired result.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.theworldcounts.com/counters/shocking_environmental_facts_and_statistics/world_population_clock_live'

response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')
population = soup.find(class_='item-content').find(class_='counter').text
# population = soup.select_one('.item-content > p.counter').text
print(population)
```